# Pygame Tower Shoots Multiple Bullets How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/ce7abeda7f0c89e520a906716b5fe5f0) I have enemys that move throught the screen and my problem is that my tower is shooting more then 1 bullet I just want it to shoot only a single bullet I tried making it so it only shoots 1 bullet at the enemys but it keeps shooting multiple bullets my enemies are in a list

```
    for shootss in shootsright:
        shootss.x += shootss.xspeed
        shootss.y += shootss.yspeed

        if shootss.x > 500 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0: 
            shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))

    
    if attack1.x == 90000:
        timer += 1
        if timer > 50:
            timer = 0
            for monster in monsters:
                for one in range(len(monsters)-1,-1,-1):
                        BULLET_SPEED = 17
                        start_x = round(-580+680)
                        start_y = round(-380+780)
                        target_x = monsters[one].x+monsters[one].width//2
                        target_y = monsters[one].y+monsters[one].width//2
                        delta_x, delta_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
                        distance = math.sqrt(delta_x ** 2 + delta_y ** 2)
                        dir_x = BULLET_SPEED * delta_x / distance
                        dir_y = BULLET_SPEED * delta_y / distance
                        distance = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
                        if distance > 0:
                            shootsright.append(enemyboolss(start_x,start_y,(0,0,0),dir_x, dir_y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition that tests whether the number of bullets in the `shootsright` list is less than 1:

```py
if attack1.x == 90000:
        timer += 1
        if timer > 50  and len(shootsright) < 1:
            # [...]
```